# Showing a list of premade suggestions while typing in a text field

Tags: javascript, php, sql

As the title says
I'm working on an mysql project and I want the text field to give suggestions with the existing users while typing in it ( admin control page to ban users .. something like that )

a simple example to explain:

when I have a text input .. I want to give suggestions to user while he is typing in it
let's say he is typing color names
so when he type b in it
before he continues a list appears giving him suggestions that we pre set like:
black
brown
blue

and then if he typed l to be bl
the the list would be:
black
blue
blabla

any advise?

Comment: Do you need any plugins or want ot do it yourself?

Comment: I wanna do it by myself .. I'm working with sql project and I want the text field to give suggestions with the existing users while typing in it ..

but if it's gonna be hard to explain then I would be thankful if you've got any plugins to accomplish the task

Comment: It is good but there is some open source plug and play codes. You can try something like this. http://daveismyname.com/autocomplete-with-php-mysql-and-jquery-ui-bp#.VCf4ABYoHwA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chechkout this page tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp it provides what you need by using ajax and php.
You only have to programmaticly fill your array with your users name